# Parsing Large XML File Using Sax

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

i am trying to parse an xml document, after searching i found out that sax is the best choice, but the document is very large (1.5 GB) waited like 7 minutes but its still running
my question is, is that normal ? or i can do better ?

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

            int c = 0;
            boolean id = false;
            boolean value = false;
            boolean orgin = false;
            boolean note = false;

            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String eName,
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                if (eName.equalsIgnoreCase("ID")) {
                    id = true;
                }

                if (eName.equalsIgnoreCase("VALUE")) {
                    value = true;
                }

                if (eName.equalsIgnoreCase("ORGIN")) {
                    orgin = true;
                }

                if (eName.equalsIgnoreCase("NOTE")) {
                    note = true;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String eName) throws SAXException {

            }

            @Override
            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                if (id) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
                    id = false;
                    System.out.println("record num : "+c++);
                }

                if (value) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
                    value = false;
                }

                if (orgin) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
                    orgin = false;
                }

                if (note) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
                    note = false;
                }

            }

        };

        saxParser.parse("./transactions.xml", handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 1.5? 1.5 mb?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411773/parsing-big-xml-files-using-sax-parser-skip-some-lines-tags

Comment: @NathanHughes i am using this for the first time, any suggestions ?

Comment: my suggestions: stop getting bad code from mkyong, read the Oracle documentation, and follow sharonbn's advice.

Comment: @NathanHughes can you tell me why it is so bad ?

Comment: read what sharonbn said in the comments about the characters method. the same advice is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Answer (score 2):

1. You can save some time by changing `equalsIgnoreCase` to `equals` (unless you really encounter "ValuE" and "valUE" and "VaLuE" ...)
2. The printing is probably taking most of the time. IO operations are usually the bottleneck

Comment: i was printing to test, i am going to save the data to database, do you have any suggestion for the database ? time is important

Comment: most database engines support batch insert/update (inserting of multiple rows in one statement) - use it

Comment: the last tip I can give you from my personal experience is that you need to be aware that the parser may call `characters()` method multiple times for the same xml element and you need to concatanate the result to get the full text. you can then do the processing (DB call etc) in `endElement()`
see details here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567636/java-sax-parser-split-calls-to-characters

Comment: if you mean instance variable then yes

Answer (score 1):

If you parse such a huge file you should use Stax instead of Sax. With Stax you can skip parts of your file which makes it faster and it's faster.

> StAX is a "pull" type of API. As discussed, there are Cursor and Event Iterator APIs. There are both reading and writing sides of the API. It is more developer friendly than SAX. StAX, like SAX, does not require an entire document to be held in memory. However, unlike SAX, an entire document need not be read. Portions can be skipped. This may result in even improved performance over SAX.

([DOM vs SAX XML parsing for large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310543/dom-vs-sax-xml-parsing-for-large-files))